# Datatable class in asp.net core

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, asp.net-core

If you have tried to use SQLClient in asp.net core, you might have noticed the absence of the DataTables and DataSets, tables structures used to I/O of database.

For output data we have the option of SqlDataReader. 
But for the input data, I'm yet to find a solution to this problem -e.g. if you want pass a table to SP by parameter in framework 461, we use 'SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured and DataTable class'. 
Any ideas anyone?

Library that I use: https://github.com/XML-Travelgate/xtg-data-sqlclient

Comment: Not sure how this applies to .net core, but [_"System.Data.SqlClient supports populating table-valued parameters from DataTable, DbDataReader or IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> objects."_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx) - or you can create a custom type on the server with `CREATE TYPE dbo.xxx AS TABLE`

Comment: .net core doesn't allow you to use those object types, and I need an alternative for asp.net core. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: According to [the relevant issue on .net-core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8622) some of them _are_ available, look at [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8622#issuecomment-223673368) and then [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8622#issuecomment-223980960)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've just tried and it work.

Answer (score 5):

Solution:

```
        List<SqlDataRecord> datatable = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
        SqlMetaData[] sqlMetaData = new SqlMetaData[2];
        sqlMetaData[0] = new SqlMetaData("id", SqlDbType.Int);
        sqlMetaData[1] = new SqlMetaData("name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
        SqlDataRecord row = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);
        row.SetValues(new object[] { 1, "John" });
        datatable.Add(row);
        row = new SqlDataRecord(sqlMetaData);
        row.SetValues(new object[] { 2, "Peter" });
        datatable.Add(row);

        var task = dbBase.ExecProcedureDataTableWithParamsAsync<object>("VIEWTABLE", new List<SqlParameter>()
            {
                new SqlParameter()
                {
                     ParameterName = "@paramtable",
                     SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                     Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                     Value = datatable
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

DataTable, DataSet etc can now be implemented using .NET Core 2.0 and Visual Studio 2017 Preview 15.3 +