# Passing a table as an input parameter to Dapper in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dapper, table-valued-parameters

While trying to pass a table in as a parameter to a stored procedure via Dapper, I came across [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24633764/336648), which indicates that it is directly supported in Dapper.

In .NET core however, [DataTable seems not to be implemented](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/8622), so this does not work.

Is there another easy way of passing a custom / user-defined table in as a parameter to a stored procedure using Dapper?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass a table-valued parameter to Dapper in .NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132350/how-do-i-pass-a-table-valued-parameter-to-dapper-in-net-core)

Answer (score 4):

For now, you will have to create a class that implements SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters for each table value type.

**Modified example (not tested)**

http://todothinkofname.net/2016/05/30/Dapper-with-Net-core/

```
  public class ParameterTvp : SqlMapper.IDynamicParameters
  {
      private readonly IEnumerable<string> _parameters;

      public ParameterTvp(IEnumerable<string> parameters)
      {
          _parameters = parameters;
      }

      public void AddParameters(IDbCommand command, SqlMapper.Identity identity)
      {
          var sqlCommand = (SqlCommand) command;
          sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          var items = new List<SqlDataRecord>();
          foreach (var param in _parameters)
          {
              var rec = new SqlDataRecord(new SqlMetaData("Parameter", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100));
              rec.SetString(0, param);
              items.Add(rec);
          }

          var p = sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@param", SqlDbType.Structured);
          p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
          p.TypeName = "ParameterTableType";
          p.Value = items;
      }
  }
```

**Usage**

```
  using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
    var parameters = new ParameterTvp(new List<string>() { "XXXXXXXX" });
    connection.Execute("test", parameters);
  }
```

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132350/is-there-a-way-to-pass-a-tvp-to-dapper-on-net-core-right-now) another example on stack.

Comment: Can you move some sample code from linked resource back here?

Comment: @VMAtm I added a modified code example from that link.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>`, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872989/datatable-class-in-asp-net-core). It's in System.Data, and it's not deprecated.